# Mono returns ConsoleApp: EPIC FAIL

Tags: mono

After following the installation [instructions](https://github.com/Radarr/Radarr/wiki/Installation#debian--ubuntu) now I'm looking at the error below.

Command

```
sudo /usr/bin/mono --debug /opt/Radarr/Radarr.exe --nobrowser
```

Returns (tldr)

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceProcess, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

What did I miss?

---

Detail:

```
   Can't find custom attr constructor image: /opt/Rad
arr/NLog.dll mtoken: 0x0a00002e due to: Could not 
load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Versio
n=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c5
61934e089' or one of its dependencies.
```

more detail

```
 [Fatal] ConsoleApp: EPIC FAIL! 

 [v0.2.0.1480] System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Exception of type 'System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException' was thrown.
 Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceProcess, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes(System.Reflection.Assembly,bool)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes () [0x00000] in <a1ae6166591d4020b810288d19af38d4>:0 
   at NzbDrone.Common.Composition.ContainerBuilderBase..ctor (NzbDrone.Common.EnvironmentInfo.IStartupContext args, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] assemblies) [0x00046] in C:\pr
 ojects\radarr-usby1\src\NzbDrone.Common\Composition\ContainerBuilderBase.cs:27                                                                                                       
   at Radarr.Host.MainAppContainerBuilder..ctor (NzbDrone.Common.EnvironmentInfo.StartupContext args, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] assemblies) [0x00000] in C:\projects\radarr-
 usby1\src\NzbDrone.Host\MainAppContainerBuilder.cs:27                                                                                                                                
   at Radarr.Host.MainAppContainerBuilder.BuildContainer (NzbDrone.Common.EnvironmentInfo.StartupContext args) [0x00032] in C:\projects\radarr-usby1\src\NzbDrone.Host\MainAppContainer
 Builder.cs:23                                                                                                                                                                        
   at Radarr.Host.Bootstrap.Start (NzbDrone.Common.EnvironmentInfo.StartupContext startupContext, Radarr.Host.IUserAlert userAlert, System.Action`1[T] startCallback) [0x00045] in C:\p
 rojects\radarr-usby1\src\NzbDrone.Host\Bootstrap.cs:35                                                                                                                               
   at NzbDrone.Console.ConsoleApp.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00029] in C:\projects\radarr-usby1\src\NzbDrone.Console\ConsoleApp.cs:37 
 System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceProcess, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies
 .                                                                                                                                                                                    
 File name: 'System.ServiceProcess, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
 ..
```

Comment: Missing `libmono-system-servicemodel4.0a-cil` ?

Comment: `/opt`? looks like you didn't install mono in a standard way so you might be having these problems because of that; how did you install it?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue on Ubuntu 20.04 by installing the `mono-devel` package instead of `mono-runtime`.